# How to upload and mail the same attachment file in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am using rails 4.

Can any one please suggest , what is the best way to upload a pdf file and the same time mail this file?

Comment: So what have you considered already?

Answer (score 0):

For uploading, you can use the [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) library. Is pretty easy to use. And for sending an Email, you can follow [this part](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#cha-account_activation_and_password_reset) of the [Rails Tutorial Book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) which shows you how to setup and send emails.